# Is testing an essential part of scrum?

Tags: testing, methodology

I don't know if StackOverflow is the right place for this question, but I am still going to ask it.

Recently I have been doing some research on software methodologies, and I have one question that came up, on which I could find a conclusive answer;

Is testing an (essential) part of Scrum, or can this be seen as a separate method? I know that when practicing a software methodology things can be difference in practice to the things described in the theory. But in this case I just want the plain facts/description of testing in relationship with Scrum.

Comment: When you say "testing", what kind of testing are you refering to?

Comment: Scrum is a project managment methodolgy and as such has nothing to say about software engineering.

Comment: @Jamie: Testing the the sense of, finding out if created functionality/user interaction works. @Bedwyr: Scrum might be for project management, but testing is an aspect that can also be separate from software engineering. If your statement implies I should have placed my question somewhere else, do you have any suggestions? @Etienne: I agree, none of the methodologies are religions, but for my research I just want to know the facts.

Comment: I think you're okay with this question being here, it matches two of the four possible FAQ points: "software tools commonly used by programmers" and "matters that are unique to the programming profession".

Comment: @MrThys: if you don't test  your code, how do you know if it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I think it's more correct to say that testing is a vital part of the *agile* process.

The *scrum* is the project management side of things, getting the user stories from the customer for a specific sprint and then letting the team loose to do their work, with the daily scrum meetings.

So, while testing may be part of the deliverables decided during the initial get-together with the customer, and it might be raised in the daily scrum meetings, it's not really *required* for the scrum process to work. The customer may (foolishly) not have a testing requirement and the developers may strike no testing problems.

Answer (score 1):

Testing can be a part of your 'Definition of Done' or you can designate testing/defect reduction sprints. Ultimately it depends on your release schedule, how your business is performed and your customers requirements and expectations.

The scrum process does not declare that any particular type of testing has to be done within the confines of a sprint.

But as an aside, you will find much more value if you can automate your testing processes.

We find it easier to include all of the testing as a part of the sprint process. The reason for that is, having 'testing sprints' allows for compound complexities if a defect is introduced in say, sprint one, but testing and defect resolution doesnt occur until say, sprint 8.